# How to make a div scrollable without scaling its contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want a table displayed as a grid.The table is held by a div. In case it extends the div's dimension I want to be able to scroll the div in order to see the entire table.The table content is generated in the script. I also defined some css classes.

```js
        var rows = 500;
        var cols = 500;
        PopulateGrid();

        function PopulateGrid() {
          var table = document.getElementById("GridTable");
          for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              var td = document.createElement('TD')
              tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
          }
        }
```

```css
        td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
        }
        table {
          border-spacing: 0px;
        }
        .GridContainer {
          height: 650px;
          width: 1447px;
          overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="GridContainer">
    <table id="GridTable"></table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Unfortunately the dt width is scaled while its height seems to correspond with the value defined in css. Am I missing some css property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width on TD elements is a bit odd, and the rules can be a bit complex.  You are thinking that the table width should be the sum of the individual td elements, but it works in reverse. The minimum required size for the table is determined as well as the size it would like it to be, then it tries to determine sane values for the widths of the TDs.  The following works, and it would also work if you set the table width to 500*50px (25000px).

```js
var rows = 500;
var cols = 500;
PopulateGrid();

function PopulateGrid() {
  var table = document.getElementById("GridTable");
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD')
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
.GridContainer {
  height: 650px;
  width: 1447px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="GridContainer">
    <table id="GridTable"></table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Initially your solution did solve my problem. I had to unmark it as answer though. The problem is, as soon as I set the rows and columns value to something that does not extend the div's dimensions the dt-width gets streched to fill the div, even with min-width (and max-width) values. This issue does not appear in JSFiddle but in every browser I run my webapplication in.

Comment: Then I suggest your problem isn't in the code I've given, but something else you've done to break it in your web application.

Comment: turns out I set the table css to width: 100% which caused that issue. Your answer was the solution.